# JavaScript external slideshow pointing to div in html

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm moving a website from aspx to html.  The slideshow worked fine in aspx, but not in html.  I must point the external javascript to the correct `<div>`.  I am a newbie.  Do I change the script or do I add something before the `<div>`?

Here's the script:

```
<script src="js/jquery.cycle.xxx.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testImages').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        pager: '#fbPager',
        pause: 1,
        timeout: 8000
    });
});
</script>
```

And here's the `<div>` containing the images:

```
<div id="xxxxx 2">
   <div id="testImages2">
       <a href="page1.html" target="_blank">
           <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxx" /></a>
       <a href="page2.html"> 
           <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxx" /></a> 
       <a href="page3.html"> 
           <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxx" /></a> 
       <a href="page4.html"> 
           <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxx" /></a> 
       <a href="http://www.5.com/" target="_blank"> 
           <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxx" height="200px" width="300px" style="border: none" /></a> 
       <a href="http://www.6.htm" target="_blank"> 
           <img src="images/6.jpg" alt="xxxxxxxxxx" /></a>
</div>

                    <div id="nxNav2">
                    <div id="px2"> <a href="#" title="xxxxxxx"> 
                         <img src="images/px.png" alt="xxxxxx" height="22" width="16" /></a></div>
                    <div id="xxPager2"></div>
                    <div id="nx2"> <a href="#" title="xxxxxxx"> 
                         <img src="images/nx.png" alt="xxxxx" height="22" width="16" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include jQuery just before you include the jQuery plugin...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/your/path/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.cycle.xxx.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

Also, you are selecting `#testImages` in your script:

```
$('#testImages').cycle({ ....
```

But your `<div>` is called `#testImages2` in your HTML:

```
<div id="testImages2">
```

You'll have to edit one or the other to make those the same.

Comment: Wow, do I feel dumb.  testImage is what a needed.  Thank you for pointing this out.  I should have checked more closely.

Comment: OK, got it all working in IE versions.  The pager buttons that hover over the images do not work in Firefox, Opera, or Google Chrome and photos do not rotate.  Worked in aspx but not in html.  Anyone with an issue in these browsers?  Shouldn't my jQuery fix this?

Comment: @sgking:  That seems like a whole new question, right?  Since I solved this one, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the green checkmark.  Then start a new topic for your hover button hover issue and I'll try to assist you the best I can.

Comment: @sgking:  I'm doing my best to help you on your new question too... so perhaps, at least, you can "accept" this answer now?  We'll both gain [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) points.  Thank-you.